# NodeJs related to Hapi.js bug - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm working on rendering the basic starting 'Hello, world' view of my Nodejs project based on the MVC model in [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/node-js-mvc-application/).

However, I couldn't believe after I wrote down bunches of js scripts, I tested with running the server script with `node server.js`, I kept getting this error as in the screenshot below:

[image]

I thought there was definitely something wrong with my Nodejs package `Hapi` with the incompatible version, but its version is even updated than the version used **in the tutorial.**

I checked the code line by line with the one given in the phase of the tutorial, but couldn't find anything wrong. So it should be something wrong in the server code. So what really goes wrong here? See the notes in the `server.js` code below:

```
'use strict';

//create all related dependencies 
const Hapi = require('hapi'); 
const Hoek = require('hoek'); 
const Settings = require('./settings');

//instantiate server object with connection port of Settings 
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({port: Settings.port}); 

//create a testing route and initiate the HTTP call
server.route(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: (request, reply) => {
            reply('Hello, this is the Nodejs project for Dota2Insight');
        }
    }
);

server.start((err) => {
  Hoek.assert(!err, err);

  console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

I'm very inexperienced with Nodejs.

Comment: Check your version of Hapi because a new one with breaking changes came out in Nov. It's possible you are running < V17 and the tutorial expects V16 or visa versa. It is also possible you are running an old version of node because its failing to execute an async function.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm trying your suggestions now

Comment: I fixed it by upgrading my Nodejs package, as well as decreasing my Hapi.js's version to 16.x.x for solving the syntax error related to it. Once again, thank for your suggestion!

Comment: Nice work. Hapi can be a little tricky sometimes. I think it has a little more learning curve than Express.js, but its also great.The maintainer is very serious about making sure it does what it's supposed to do very well. I'm excited for you on your pathway. node.js is awesome and so is isomorphic JavaScript.